# gerrit to github replication: jsch issues

Tags: ssh, github, jsch, gerrit

Trying to setup replication from gerrit to my github repo. Getting this stacktrace:

> [2011-09-20 00:11:58,470] ERROR com.google.gerrit.server.git.PushReplication : Cannot replicate to git@github.com:myuser/myrepo.git
>   org.eclipse.jgit.errors.TransportException: git@github.com:myuser/myrepo.git: Session.connect: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
>           at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.JschConfigSessionFactory.getSession(JschConfigSessionFactory.java:138)
>           at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.SshTransport.getSession(SshTransport.java:121)
>           at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportGitSsh$SshFetchConnection.(TransportGitSsh.java:248)
>           at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportGitSsh.openFetch(TransportGitSsh.java:147)
>           at com.google.gerrit.server.git.PushOp.listRemote(PushOp.java:358)
>           at com.google.gerrit.server.git.PushOp.generateUpdates(PushOp.java:312)
>           at com.google.gerrit.server.git.PushOp.pushVia(PushOp.java:258)
>           at com.google.gerrit.server.git.PushOp.runImpl(PushOp.java:213)
>           at com.google.gerrit.server.git.PushOp.run(PushOp.java:166)
>           at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:98)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:206)
>           at com.google.gerrit.server.git.WorkQueue$Task.run(WorkQueue.java:324)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
>
> Caused by: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Session.connect: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
>           at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:504)
>           at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.JschConfigSessionFactory.getSession(JschConfigSessionFactory.java:128)

My config files are as follows:

replication.config:

```
[remote "github"]
url = git@github.com:myuser/${name}.git
push = +refs/heads/*:refs/heads/*
push = +refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*
timeout = 5
replicationDelay = 0
authGroup = Administrators
```

secure.config:

```
[database]
    password = secret
[ssh]
    file = /home/gerrit2/.ssh/config
```

.ssh/config:

```
Host github.com:
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
  PreferredAuthentications publickey
```

I tried running

```
ssh -i etc/ssh_host_dsa_key git@github.com
ssh -i etc/ssh_host_rsa_key git@github.com
ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa git@github.com
ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_dsa  git@github.com
```

and was able to "hit" github so the keys are imported OK, not sure what the problem is,
any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: A SocketTimeoutException *Signals that a timeout has occurred on a socket read or accept*. Did you try to increase the timeout value?

Comment: Thank you I should have tried it before! Works a charm after setting timeout to 60 in replication.config (as opposed to 5).

Comment: I didn't think that the solution would be that easy, I only wanted to rule out one possible reason. I made this comment (with some additional information) into an answer. Feel free to accept it (using the green checkmark button) if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the name of the exception `SocketTimeoutException` says (and its [documentation details](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?java/net/SocketTimeoutException.html)):

> Signals that a timeout has occurred on a socket read or accept.

Looking in the [documentation of Gerrit's replication.config](http://gerrit.googlecode.com/svn/documentation/2.0/config-replication.html#remote.name.timeout):

> *remote.<name>.timeout*
>
> Number of seconds to wait for a network read or write to complete before giving up and declaring the remote side
>      is not responding. If 0, there is no timeout, and the push client waits indefinitely.
>
> A timeout should be large enough to mostly transfer the objects to the other side. 1 second may be too small
>     for larger projects, especially over a WAN link, while 10-30 seconds is a much more reasonable timeout value.
>
> Defaults to 0 seconds, wait indefinitely.

Your value is 5 seconds, you could try it with a larger value instead.

(The problem is only indirectly related to JSch - JSch's [`Session.connect(int)`](http://epaul.github.com/jsch-documentation/simple.javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/Session.html#connect%28int%29) will simply take the timeout parameter and pass it on to the Socket it creates. That [reminds me](https://github.com/ePaul/jsch-documentation/issues/2) that I should document which unit this timeout is for JSch - seconds or milliseconds.)